# Why won't this simple RewriteRule work?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This should be simple but I cannot figure it out. I have this very simple mod_rewrite rule and it just doesn't want to work. This is the entire contents of the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

If I call the URL domain.com/foo it should rewrite it to index.php?page=foo. But instead, it rewrites it to index.php?page=index.php. I have tried multiple URLs:

- index.php?page=foo
- index.php
- /foo
- /

In all cases, PHP acts as if 'page' is set to "index.php". It isn't a fault with index.php because I replaced the entire contents of index.php with a script that simple echoed the value of 'page' and it still comes out as index.php.

Really lost where I'm going wrong here, any help would be awesome!

Thanks

Adrian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason you can't use something simpler, such as:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

If you're trying to keep existing pages from being re-written, then the `!-f` will take care of that (`if file does not exist` and `if directory does not exist`, then `re-write`)

Comment: I actually hadn't thought of that (avoiding re-writing actual pages), but that is definitely something I need to do! This works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your looking for. Unfortunately it doesn't really work well if the URL has other GET arguments (IE, /some/url/path?page=1).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

**Better idea.**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

The QSA flag will forward the GET params and then in index.php use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `parse_url` to route the request.

From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html:

```
'qsappend|QSA' (query string append)
This flag forces the rewriting engine to append a query string part
in the substitution string to the existing one instead of replacing it.
Use this when you want to add more data to the query string via a rewrite rule.
```

Comment: For the time being I won't have multiple get arguments, I just need this to work for now. I tried what you gave me and it still produces the same result.